# VBA Get Username on OSX (or Mac alternative to Environ("username"))

Tags: excel, vba, macos, excel-2010

My task has been to create a secure (Windows version) Excel workbook that uses macros to validate whether a user has permission to view the contents. In Excel 2010 for Windows, I use the `Environ("username")` function to accomplish this.

The problem I'm running into is that some users in the organization use a Mac to do their daily work, and `Environ` does not work with OSX.

Does anyone know of an alternate way to find the username of a Mac? I've looked online but all I can find is how to find the unique identifier of the computer, not the username.

Is what I'm attempting to do even possible with Mac?

Any information is appreciated!

Comment: At the risk of pointing out the obvious: having the right “username” doesn’t guarantee you are authorized to view the spreadsheet. Creating a new user on your computer is pretty easy...

Comment: @Floris Great point! It’s been many years since I worked on this project and I’d do it differently today. But even then, this was in an organization setting where creating new users wasn’t possible by anyone who’d have been using these files. Still, I’d do this way different today than I did back then based on knowledge and skills I’ve acquired since.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use AppleScript to return the Username and run that from VBA.

The following function should do the trick.

```
Function GetUserNameMac() As String
    Dim sMyScript As String

    sMyScript = "set userName to short user name of (system info)" & vbNewLine & "return userName"

    GetUserNameMac = MacScript(sMyScript)
End Function
```

Comment: Thank you so much, @CuberChase! I'm going to test this with one of my users as soon as I can tomorrow and I'll let you know if I have any questions or if I can't get it to work properly.

Comment: No problems.  I tested it on my Mac and it works but if there are any issues, leave a comment.

Comment: I just tested the solution you provided. It worked like a charm! I am so grateful for your help with this. Thank you, thank you, thank you!

Answer (score 8):

`Environ("USER")` and `Environ("LOGNAME")` return the same thing on the Mac as the MacScript answer.

Comment: Note that the strings MUST be in UPPER CASE to work as described on the Mac.

Answer (score 0):

I just found this question while looking for a macOS-equivalent to Environ("COMPUTERNAME") as I have been using this:

```
MacScript("do shell script ""hostname""")
```

If you want to get all three common user IDs, this returns the user account name:

```
MacScript("do shell script ""stat -f$Su /dev/console""")
```

And this returns the numeric user ID, which is often 501:

```
MacScript("do shell script ""stat -f$Uu /dev/console""")
```

And this returns the user's real name (as displayed in the menu bar):

```
MacScript("do shell script ""id -P $(stat -f%Su /dev/console | cut -d : -f 8""")
```