# Authenticate users in active directory

Tags: macos, excel, applescript, vba

There is a need to authenticate user in active directory from Excel VBA. I have tried for windows and it is working fine but the same code is not running on mac machines since the "Active DS Type Library" is missing in IOS. So looking for some Apple scripts that will do the same thing and I can run using "MacScript()" function available in VBA.

Comment: [Does this help?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847080/vba-get-username-on-osx-or-mac-alternative-to-environusername) It's not exactly what you're looking for (I think), but it might help you get closer to the answer...