# Saving an Excel Sheet as PDF automatically through VBA to Dropbox using multiple users on Macintosh

Tags: excel, vba, dropbox

This is my first post so please let me know if I have entered anything improperly or ways to improve my questions.

I have a time sheet spread sheet which I would like to be saved to a company dropbox folder once filled out and closed.  I can get it to work using only a single user but I would like to be able to save it regardless of the user.  I have seen a similar question in the linked post [VBA: How to save Excel Workbook to Desktop regardless of user?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17551238/vba-how-to-save-excel-workbook-to-desktop-regardless-of-user)
however it does not solve my problem as I am on a mac and I don't know how to define the username.  I had thought about the person uploading the timesheet to enter their name as the user however they do not each have their own computer and will be sharing.

I am using **Sheebs** as the user name in my code

here is what i have for code so far

```
    Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

MSG1 = MsgBox("Upload Timesheet?", vbOKCancel, "Save Timesheet and Update Payroll Matrix?")
If MSG1 = Cancel Then GoTo lastline Else: GoTo Saveas


Saveas:


Dim fName As String
With ActiveSheet
    fName = .Range("D8").Value & "-" & .Range("D7").Value
    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:="Macintosh HD:Users:Sheebs:Dropbox:Time        Sheet:" & .Range("B8").Value & ":" & .Range("C8").Value & ":" & fName, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With

lastline:
ThisWorkbook.Saved = True

End Sub
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847080/vba-get-username-on-osx-or-mac-alternative-to-environusername

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From here:

[VBA Get Username on OSX (or Mac alternative to Environ("username"))](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847080/vba-get-username-on-osx-or-mac-alternative-to-environusername)

You may be able to use the function described in the link above to get the username (untested):

```
Dim fName As String
Dim uName As String
Dim savePath as String

uName = GetUserNameMac()

With ActiveSheet
    fName = .Range("D8").Value & "-" & .Range("D7").Value
    savePath = "Macintosh HD:Users:" & uName & ":Dropbox:TimeSheet:" & _
        .Range("B8").Value & ":" & .Range("C8").Value & ":" & fName

    .ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:=savePath, _
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
        IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False
End With
```

The function:

```
Function GetUserNameMac() As String
    Dim sMyScript As String

    sMyScript = "set userName to short user name of (system info)" & vbNewLine & "return userName"

    GetUserNameMac = MacScript(sMyScript)
End Function
```

Comment: I had to change your answer slightly. For some reason it wasn't liking "uName" as part of the file name so I put the value into A105 and pulled it from there