# VBA Excel MacOs 2019 pdf export to current directory

Tags: excel, vba, macos, path

I wrote a code for PDF export in Excel for Mac Office 2019 with a variable filename.  It's working despite Mac's permission bugs with VBA saving as when using the makro for the first time Excel asks for the permission to access the concerning folder.

My question:
Can I anyhow give new users the option to choose their exporting path the first time they are using the makro or do I have to adjust the code for every new user personally?

Here's my (otherwise working) code so far:

```
Sub als_PDF_speichern_recorded_mac()

    ChDir "/Users/Admin/Documents/Dokumente/Finanzen/2021/Rechnungen 2021/"
    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
        "/Users/Admin/Documents/Dokumente/Finanzen/2021/Rechnungen 2021/Rechnung_" & ActiveSheet.Range("D11") & ".pdf" _
        , Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
End Sub
```

**EDIT**

I might have a solution working universally for Mac users. It's not following my original intent that users can choose the path at first use but it's supposed to be exporting the PDF to the current path of the workbook and creating a folder if not existing already.

Please could someone with Excel for Mac (I'm using 2019) confirm:

```
Sub exportPDF_mac()
    
'export to currentpath/greatnewfolder
    ChDir "/" & ActiveWorkbook.Path
    
    MakeFolderIfNotExist (ThisWorkbook.Path & Application.PathSeparator & "greatnewfolder")

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:= _
        "/" & ActiveWorkbook.Path & "/greatnewfolder/greatfile_" & ActiveSheet.Range("D11") & ".pdf" _
        , Quality:=xlQualityMinimum, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas _
        :=False, OpenAfterPublish:=True
        
End Sub

Function MakeFolderIfNotExist(Folderstring As String)
' Ron de Bruin, 2-March-2019
' http://www.rondebruin.nl/mac/mac010.htm
    Dim ScriptToMakeFolder As String
    Dim TestStr As String
    Dim FolderStr As String
    
    If Val(Application.Version) < 15 Then
        ScriptToMakeFolder = "tell application " & Chr(34) & _
                             "Finder" & Chr(34) & Chr(13)
        ScriptToMakeFolder = ScriptToMakeFolder & _
                "do shell script ""mkdir -p "" & quoted form of posix path of (" & _
                        Chr(34) & Folderstring & Chr(34) & ")" & Chr(13)
        ScriptToMakeFolder = ScriptToMakeFolder & "end tell"
        On Error Resume Next
        MacScript (ScriptToMakeFolder)
        On Error GoTo 0
    Else
        FolderStr = MacScript("return POSIX path of (" & _
                        Chr(34) & Folderstring & Chr(34) & ")")
        On Error Resume Next
        TestStr = Dir(FolderStr & "*", vbDirectory)
        On Error GoTo 0
        If TestStr = vbNullString Then
            MkDir FolderStr
        End If
    End If
End Function
```

Thanks in advance!
Thomas

Comment: If you are just trying to get the unique path for a given username then maybe take a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17847080/vba-get-username-on-osx-or-mac-alternative-to-environusername) and/or try `Environ("USER")`. If you want to ask the user for the path the first time and then use that selected path other times then you would need to store the path somewhere. It could be as simple as storing the path in some cell in a worksheet.

Comment: @garbb Great, thanks. I'm gonna try that.

Comment: @garbb I maybe found a better solution than the dialog box. I tested it in different paths and it seems to work fine. The ```Active.Workbook``` code is working if you put a ```"/"``` before that as the Mac paths don't start with "C:" but automatically in the base level of the path. If you have a Mac and Office for Mac, could you maybe give the edited code above a try? Thanks!

Comment: I don't have a mac, sorry